# SPSearch in CocoaLibSpotify

Tags: ios, spotify

I'm looking at CocoaLibSpotify, and trying to get a simple search request working.
I make the request like this:

```
SPSearch *search = [[SPSearch alloc] initWithSearchQuery:@"Adele" inSession:[SPSession sharedSession] ];
```

And am then polling for the search to return with:

```
[search searchInProgress]
```

But I never see searchInProgress return a NO - ie. the search does not appear to ever complete.

I've searched through the documentation and examples but it hasn't helped me to understand how to use the SPSearch correctly - would definitely welcome some help here...

Thanks,
Iain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Key-Value Observing to observe changes to the properties you need.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Is there a reason KVO catches the value change to YES but checking the value directly always returns NO?

Comment: If you're polling in a tight loop, you're actually blocking libSpotify as well, since it runs on the same thread you call it on. Since libSpotify can't operate the search properly, the search never completes.